# Are the EM waves that result from each of these processes distinguishable? Phase of light upon emission

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

In case 1, you have a single source of light that you pass through a diagonally oriented linear polarizer and then a half waveplate, such that the horizontal and vertical components become $\pi$ out of phase with each other.

In case 2, you have two <s>distinct</s> physically separate sources of light. You vertically polarize light from one and horizontally polarize light from the other. You then propagate one through a medium of an appropriate refractive index and thickness that it becomes $\pi$ out of phase with itself prior to the medium. You then combine these two lights.

**Would the light that results in case 1 be distinguishable from the light that results from case 2?** (Other than a difference in intensity. Say the two light sources in case 2 were half as bright.)

As far as I can see, it would depend on if the horizontal and vertical components of the light emitted from the original three sources were all in phase with each other. If this is true, then what would affect if they were? **When light is emitted, what affects 'where on the representative half-sinusoidal wave it starts'?**

Comment: If the sources are truly distinct, then the two cases are distinguishable. Think about it in terms of temporal coherence.

Comment: Are they distinguishable if all sources are monochromatic and of the same frequency? (Or does that mean the sources aren't distinct?)

Comment: Sources that are both monochromatic and phase locked are classically indistinguishable, so I would not apply the word "distinct" to them. If you want to analyze this in detail, you will have to broaden the definition of source to include a non-trivial spectrum. You can simplify your life by assuming two monochromatic sources with slightly different frequency to understand the basic phenomenon.

Comment: Alright. Sorry for my terminology. I meant 'distinct' in the sense that there are physically different/separate devices emitting the light. I tried to design the first question so that the only thing it depended on was the answer to the second, which is probably what I'm most interested in.

Comment: I thought that was what you meant. Distinct sources will always have slightly different spectrum and they will therefor always be incoherent, hence distinguishable.

Comment: :). Is having the same spectrum a sufficient condition for them to be **not** distinct?

Comment: No. Can you figure out why? :-) It does, by the way, really pay off to distinguish between "distinct" and "distinguishable".

Comment: They could have different intensities or polarizations? Does that count? I can't actually see how not being monochromatic would make a difference, since they'd both undergo phase shifting at the same rate.

Comment: Take two waves of slightly different frequency and calculate the phase difference as a function of time. Can it stay constant?